# geom_line() argument orientation does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to change the orientation of a geom_line() plot from left to right (along the x-axis) to top to bottom (along the y-axis), however, it does not work.

```
ggplot(economics, aes(unemploy, date)) + geom_line(orientation = "y")
```

According to the third example on this page (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) this should give me the desired plot.

I only get the following error and a line plot along the x-axis

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: orientation
```

I am using *ggplot2* version 3.2.1
Unfortunately, updating to the newer version of *ggplot2* is not really an option. (and the orientation argument should also work in 3.2.1 according to the documentation)

Comment: Works for me exactly as shown on that page without any warning. Although I am on `3.3.2`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any error, works as expected. My package version is `3.3.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked with an my old R 3.6.1 installation, which has ggplot 3.2.1. `help("geom_line")` does not document the `orientation` parameter (in contrast to my current installation with ggplot 3.3.2).

Indeed, the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html) shows that the parameter was added in ggplot 3.3.0.

You'll have to update if you want to use this parameter.